# Activate the CLOSE button

Tags: java, swing, interface, jframe

After clicking the run button, an interface prompt up.
The "Press me...." button that I created is working,however the CLOSE button at the top right corner is not working.
The only way to close is to click the STOP ICON at the console area, which I felt troublesome.
How can I use the close button?
Am I short of any codes? or am I doing it wrongly?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class TestButton1 {
    private Frame F;
    private Button B;

    public TestButton1() {
        F = new Frame("Welcome!");
        B = new Button(
                "Press Me! \nSo that, you can genarate OUTPUT result at the CONSOLE");
        B.setActionCommand("ButtonPressed");
    }

    public void launchFrame() {
        B.addActionListener(new mainclass());
        F.add(B, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        F.pack();
        F.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestButton1 guiApp = new TestButton1();
        guiApp.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is mainclass in your sample code?

Comment: @peter.petrov Is called Bmi calculator but it doesn't affect it. Purpose of 5he frame is just to show interface and click the button to show results at console.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your frame you should use:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // or exit on close
```

Comment: The question was about Frame, not about JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You may add this code

```
F.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

before

```
F.add(B, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Generally, you would only use a WindowListener when you want to do special processing before closing the frame.

Comment: FYI - This may not work if the OP sets the `setDefaultCloseOperation` to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: @peter.petrov one more question.  Is it possible to auto close the interface after I click the "press me.." button?